# Frontier package in R

Tags: r

I'm new on R and for my masterthesis I need to measure the cost efficiency of the Turkish banksector with the the help of function sfa() of the package "frontier". My dataframe has the following framework:

```
 X; BankName; Year; Labor; PhysicalCapital; Loans; Deposits; TotalCosts
 1; "HSBC"  ; 2002; 0.123;            2.19;  1200;     3200;      10.9
```

[TC stands for Total Costs, pk for Physical Capital, y for bank output (either Loans or Deposits, and pl for Labor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXX2F.png)

The first argument of the sfa() function is this formula but I couldn't figure out how to implement this in R. Is there any chance you could help me?

Comment: did you read the description of the function? It's pretty clear. Find it [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/frontier/docs/frontier)

Answer (score 0):

There is a data called front41Data included in the frontier package. Try to understand and do the same for your data.

```
# example included in FRONTIER 4.1 (cross-section data)
  data( front41Data )

# Cobb-Douglas production frontier
  cobbDouglas <- sfa( log( output ) ~ log( capital ) + log( labour ),
  data = front41Data )
  summary( cobbDouglas )
```

Comment: Does your formula corresponds to the structure of the formula of the image? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, I have no idea about the analysis, but the example give in this link:
http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/frontier/docs/frontier